# Clustering in Matlab

Tags: matlab, merge, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, linkage

Hi I am trying to cluster using linkage(). Here is the code I am trying..

```
 Y = pdist(data);
 Z = linkage(Y);
 T = cluster(Z,'maxclust',4096);
```

I am getting error as follows

```
The number of elements exceeds the maximum allowed size in
MATLAB.
Error in ==> linkage at 135
    Z = linkagemex(Y,method);
```

data size is 56710*128. How can I apply the code on small chunks of data and then merge those clusters optimally?? Or any other solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab probably cannot cluster this many objects with this algorithm.

Most likely they use distance matrixes in their implementation. A pairwise distance matrix for 56710 objects needs 56710*56709/2=1,607,983,695 entries, or some 12 GB of RAM; most likely also a working copy of this is needed. Chances are that the default Matlab data structures are not prepared to handle this amount of data (and you won't want to wait for the algorithm to finish either; probably that is why they "allow" only a certain amount).

Try using a subset, and see how well it scales. If you use 1000 instances, does it work? How long does the computation take? If you increase to 2000, how much longer does it take?

Comment: How does runtime and memory usage scale if you vary the data set size? Is it *realistic* to every go all the way to 56k? Because hierarchical clustering is known to scale badly.